# redirect to another domain, but keep the url

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have 2 vhosts: www.example1.com and www.example2.com

I have a page on www.example1.com/page.html

I want this page to be accessible in the other domain, meaning I want people to be able to get to www.example2.com/page.html and view that page that is physically on the other vhost. But the URL must display www.example2.com

I don't want to simply move the page physically to the other vhost, because it is a wordpress page and it would be a huge hassle.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible.

I suggest reverse-proxy to do that. A software like [NGinX](http://nginx.org/) does it very well, as well as apache of course (mod_proxy I recall).

Anyway, the downside of that approach is that your server (on www.example2.com) would request the page from example1 and send it through itself, and not directly from example1.

By the way - this technique is being used for load balancing as well.

Edit #1:
In nginx it's called [ngx_http_upstream_module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html).

Edit #2:
`grahaminn` is correct yet my approach displays URL "correctly" - instead of one fixed URL which would make problems of, for example, bookmark a specific page.

Answer (score 1):

Two options:

1. Use Apache ProxyPass: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass
2. Use Rewrite with [P] flag (requires mod_proxy installed)

   RewriteRule /(.*)$ http://example2.com/$1 [P]

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html

Answer (score 0):

You can just serve a page from example2.com that uses javascript or an iframe to load the content from example1.com

Comment: an iframe is actually a brilliant solution. What are the downsides of it compared to apache proxy

Comment: The first thing I can think of is that it *might* interact badly with javascript in the page, depending on what exactly you're trying to do.
You can also simply load content directly from example1 using javascript at the client.